# String interpolation in Bash

Tags: string, bash

My code

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( c=0; c<=1127; c++ ))
do
id = 9694 + c
if (id < 10000); then
    wget http://myurl.de/source/image/08_05_27_0${id}.jpg
else 
    wget http://myurl.de/source/image/08_05_27_${id}.jpg
fi
done
```

I only get

```
./get.sh: line 5: 10000: No such file or directory
--2009-05-06 11:20:36--  http://myurl.de/source/image/08_05_27_.jpg
```

without the number.

The corrected code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( c=0; c<=1127; c++ ))
do
id=$((9694+c))
if (id -lt 10000); then
    wget http://myurl.de/source/image/08_05_27_0${id}.jpg
else 
    wget http://myurl.de/source/image/08_05_27_${id}.jpg
fi
done
```

And even better:

```
for i in $(seq 9694 10821) ; do
    _U=`printf "http://myurl.de/source/image/08_05_27_%05d.jpg" $i`
    wget $_U 
done
```

Comment: I hope albrecht-haag.de don't mind you scraping every image off their website ;-)

Comment: I work for him so I guess its okay. =)

Comment: Manni is right, the text in a question must explain what are you trying to accomplish. Moreover, you don't need to c&p answers, either, just link to them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'll opt for simpler solution

```
for i in $(seq 9694 10821) ; do
    _U=`printf "http://myurl.de/source/image/08_05_27_%05d.jpg" $i`
    wget $_U 
done
```

Comment: does this add the leading 0 too?

Comment: Yes. By using %05d as formating argument to printf, that causses printf to left-pad output with zeros

Comment: This is a better answer than the others (yes, shock horror, even mine :-). Upvoting.

Comment: Wow, this is very smart. In the end I did it differently but I accept this answer as the best. – ByteNirvana

Comment: Good answer. Just note that $(...) is preferred to old \`...\`. It could look like this:

wget "http://myurl.de/source/image/08_05_27_$(printf "%05d" $i).jpg"

Answer (score 11):

You are making a couple of mistakes with bash syntax, especially when dealing with arithmetic expressions.

- You cannot put a space around the = sign when assigning to a variable.
- In the assignment to "id", to invoke arithmetic evaluation, you need to use the $(( expression )) syntax.
- For the "if" condition, you need double parentheses just like you're using with "for".

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( c=0; c<=1127; c++ )); do
  id=$((9694 + c))
  if ((id < 10000)); then
    wget http://myurl.de/source/image/08_05_27_0${id}.jpg
  else
    wget http://myurl.de/source/image/08_05_27_${id}.jpg
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what you need.

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( c=0; c<=1127; c++ ))
do
    ((id = 9694 + c))
    if [[ id -lt 10000 ]] ; then
        wget http://myurl.de/source/image/08_05_27_0${id}.jpg
    else 
        wget http://myurl.de/source/image/08_05_27_${id}.jpg
    fi
done
```

Comment: Hmm, you've edited your answer, the (( )) were missing from around the assignment line in the original version.

Comment: Just to make it clear, the code is now fine and works.   And I did cut'n'paste your original code, ran it, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
id=$((9694+c))
...
if [[ id < 10000 ]]; then
```